# Is there any indication that Gon will get his nen back?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

If he can't that essentially renders the main character useless right. Also if he gets his nen back do you think he'll get a different type since he came back from almost being dead. Is there any chance he'll get a different nen nature.

Comment: Still reading the current arc and from until the chapter I've read, no indication whatsoever. Regarding the follow-up questions, they seem to be primarily opinion-based and is asking for speculations of a future event, which are not allowed here so an edit might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There have been no blatant indications in the manga or anime to show that he will get his Nen back.

In most other shonen manga's you would expect a protagonist who loses their powers to eventually regain them stronger or in a different way.  This is best seen in Bleach where Ichigo and his allies does this many times. As Hunter x Hunter frequently is designed to subvert expectations, however, there is no reason to presume Gon will get his powers back.